# Zend Form Checkbox checked

Tags: php, zend-framework, checkbox, zend-form

How can I make checkbox checked in Zend Framework depending on the variable value?
For example, I have `$some_value = 'yes';` - checkbox should be checked, unchecked otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: And inside out? What are you asking?

Comment: @Iznogood, I guess by `inside out`, he means `vice versa`.

Comment: @shamittomar Right that does not tell us much about his question. But hey if you understand him feel free to answer. I think he should post some code and a much better explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thought I would have a go at this, your question is badly written, but I will do my best. There are are a few solutions below, I have not tested them all. Give them  a try.

Example 1

```
 // create your checkbox
 $checkbox_element = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox("mycheckbox");     


 // Set the value to 1 if needed
 if($some_value == "yes")
 {
      $checkbox_element->setValue(1);
 }
```

Example 2

```
 // Check if value is set
 if($some_value == "yes")
 {
      // Create checkbox element and Set the attribute 'checked' to 'checked' 
      $checkbox_element = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox("mycheckbox", array("checked" => "checked"); 
 }   
 else
 {
      // Othrewise create the checkbox which is not checked
      $checkbox_element = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox("mycheckbox"); 
 }
```